# grouping and logical implication in math mode

Tags: latex

How could I typeset a formula like this:

[image: boolean operations]

It should respect typographic rules, but it must look very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you meant to use logical disjunction and logical implication)

```
\[
\left.\begin{array}{l}
    A = T \\ B = F 
\end{array}\right\} 
\implies A \lor B = T \lor F = T
\]
```

Comment: Yeah it's about disjunctions. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `aligned` environment (requires the `amsmath` package), e.g.

```
\left. \begin{aligned}
   A &= T \\
   B &= F 
\end{aligned} \right\} \implies A \vee B = T \vee F = T
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it looks nice, unfortunately 1. I couldn't find that on ctan, nor is there any "aligned.sty" on the web (or I couldn't find it) and 2. I'm already using a bunch of packages, so I prefer to keep it slim by using the solution above. You could put a link to the package and I'll certainly upvote it, since it could be a feasible solution for others.

Comment: @Flavius: If you Google for `"aligned environment"` the first few links mention `amsmath` already.

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you want:

```
\[ 
  \left.
  \begin{array}{c}
    A = T\\
    B = F
  \end{array}
  \right\}
  \Rightarrow A \vee B = T \vee F = T
\]
```